# How can I find values that make a matrix Linearly Dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-1&0&1\\0&0&a&3\\0&0&0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

For what choices (if any) of real numbers a and b are the
rows of A linearly dependent? Justify your response.

I figured out that the free variables in this matrix are x2 and x4. However, I got the matrixes [-1/2 , -1 , -3/a , 1] and [-2, 1 , 0 , 0 ]. I'm not sure what my next step would be.

Comment: It's nigh on impossible to read your problem.. See here for a tutorial on latex http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Hopefully the problem is clear now.

Comment: You just need to write down what linear dependence means in this case. Namely, the 2nd and 3rd rows are dependent if there exist $k_1$ and $k_2$ in your field, real numbers, such that $k_1 [0,0,a,3] + k_2 [0,0,0,b]= [0,0,0,0]$. Solving this simple equation, you clearly find what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make them linearly dependent, you must find nontrivial $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ such that
$$\lambda_1 \pmatrix{2\\-1\\0\\1} + \lambda_2 \pmatrix{0\\0\\a\\3} + \lambda_3 \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\b} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0}$$
The first two equations enforce $\lambda_1 = 0$ and the third equation enforces $\lambda_2 a = 0$, the fourth $3\lambda_2 + b\lambda_3 = 0$. To get a solution with $\lambda_2 \ne 0$ or $\lambda_3 \ne 0$ there are two possibilities

- $b\ne 0$ then $\lambda_2 = -\lambda_3$ but this implies for nonzero $\lambda_3$. that $a = 0$:
  $a=0, b\ne 0$
- $b=0$ then we can chose $\lambda_2 = 0$ and $\lambda_3$ as well as $a$ arbitrary

Summing up: $a$ is arbitrary. If $a\ne0$ we must chose $b=0$, else $b$ is arbitrary as well.

Comment: @vadim123 Tanks, fixed. :)